# Change when phone beeps for notifications

Tags: notifications, audio, sony-xperia-z2

My phone makes a lot of noise when it's not in use. I think this is because apps running in the background have experienced an event, like Clash of the Clans. How can I change this? I'd really like to find out what apps just made my phone beep. I'm running Cyanogenmod 12.1 with android 5.1.1 (though soon to upgrade to android 6).

Comment: i didnt get your question...do you want to turn off your notification for a particlar app or something like that..???

Comment: @Anko basically yes, i want to turn off notifications for a particular app, I just don't know which app keeps making the phone beep

Comment: Maybe not the answer you want, but can you clear all notifications and check your phone every time it beeps? There should be a notification relevant to the beep. If you think that the app's notification is annoying, you can open the app and check the in-app settings for notification (generally, there's a notification setting in the app itself). Otherwise, follow Anko's answer if you don't care about their notifications.

Comment: @AndrewT. good point, I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

Lets take an example that its your clash of clans app(as u mentioned it in the question)...go in settings -> app -> select that app -> there will be a checkbox which says 'show notification'. Uncheck it

Comment: Ok thanks. So unchecking this will prevent audio notifications as well as the notification being added to the lock screen?

Comment: Yup.... If you appreciate you can give a +1 to my answer